# How to change Connection in Entity Framework using Auto Fac Instance as per request ?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, autofac

I'm using Autofac (DI) for creating instance as per request. like

```
 public class UserController : BaseController
{       
    public CUsersController(ICUserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
}
```

All the project working Great but i have scenario where i need to change db connection in my DBContext class and get data according to that database with my same dbcontext because of i'm working in SAS based application with Code First Approach.

My Problem is that While executing MVC Controller Constructor  Autfac has created instance of MyDBContext class as per request and i'm not able to pass my connection string before creating instance of MyDBContext class.

Please Suggest me any idea .

Thanks

Comment: Did you get any answer for this ? I also need solution for this

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options for changing inputs to constructed objects.

**The first option is to use a strategy pattern.** I assume you have some way to determine what the connection string (or other value) is at runtime by the time you need to construct the database context. Put that logic into an interface implementation, like this:

```
public interface IConnectionStringProvider
{
  string GetConnectionString();
}

public class EnvironmentConnectionStringProvider : IConnectionStringProvider
{
  public string GetConnectionString()
  {
    return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("connection");
  }
}
```

Obviously your logic is probably not going to get it from the environment. But the point is, the logic *does* know how to get it, and you need to package that logic.

Once you do that, you can register your context creation as a lambda, like this:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<EnvironmentConnectionStringProvider>()
       .As<IConnectionStringProvider>();
builder.Register(ctx => {
          var provider = ctx.Resolve<IConnectionStringProvider>();
          return new DbContext(provider.GetConnectionString());
        }).As<IDbContext>();
```

Every time the context gets resolved, the lambda runs and gets the appropriate connection string.

**The second option is to use parameters at registration time.** [There is documentation on how to use parameters during registration here.](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html)

A parameter usage might look like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<DbContext>()
   .As<IDbContext>()
   .WithParameter(
     new ResolvedParameter(
       (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(string) && pi.Name == "configSectionName",
       (pi, ctx) => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("connection")));
```

**You can combine these, too.** The `ResolvedParameter` option there, you'll see, takes in a `ParameterInfo` and a context from which you can resolve things. You can package up your strategy and then apply it using parameters rather than in a lambda registration.

Between these two mechanisms, you should have the tools you need to switch your connection string during construction/instantiation time as needed.

Comment: Thanks! 
I'm working in SAS based app. App has connected with DB with according to their subdomin. it is working fine.In this app I have a module where super admin able to view the user of all the sub application. Here is a drop down according to that i'm sending ajax request for data to server . According to app Id . I have need to get user from that app database. I'm using Autofac so at the time of request to ASP.NET MVC controller constructor has created services object and service has created DBContext object and after that i'm not able to modify that connection according to app DB.

Comment: Instead of trying to change the connection after it's already been created, change it at the time of creation via the above patterns. Autofac is only ever in action when an object is built up. After that, it's all app code. There is nothing in Autofac that says, "Create this object, then later after some of my app code has run, give me a callback so I can re-create the object." If you need that, you have to build it custom yourself.

Comment: The above patterns will work if we know the connection string. i'm getting db credential according to app id and after that storing in session . using this session i'm try to pass the connection in dbcontext class object .

Comment: Again, all Autofac offers is parameters - either [during registration](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html) or [during resolution](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/parameters.html). There's even [lazy/deferred evaluation using Lazy<T>](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html). But there's no "swap this thing in after Autofac's already run." **You may need to redesign the way the context gets created in the first place to accommodate for your unique situation.** Unfortunately, that's about the limit of help I can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I am achieving this through something similar to the following code (it's for a web api rather than mvc project but it should be easy to translate)

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
var assemblys = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
builder.RegisterApiControllers(assemblys.Where(t => t.FullName.Contains("WebApi")).ToArray())
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: Thanks For your reply but i have already done autofac registration in my Global.ascx file . I have need to modify or recreate MyDBContext instance after created instance by autofac.